# How to get all items with the same value in list of lists c# LINQ?

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

I have a to add a specific requirement in a piece of code already implemented. 
The data structure is something of this sort:

```
public class Module
{
    public string Type;
    public string ID;
    public List<Point> Points = new List<Point>();
 }

public class Point
{
    public string Type;
    public string Location;
    public string Connection;
}
```

Originally LINQ was used to return all modules which certain characteristics

```
List<Module> miList = Modules.Where(m => m.Type != null 
                             && m.ID == "A" 
                             && m.Points.Where(t => t.Connection == "" 
                                && SimilarPoint(t.Type, x).ToList())
                             .Count() > 0)
                             .ToList();
```

with x an input to the function. The new requirement dictates that the modules returned shall all have points with Connection equal to "" and the same value in the Location field.

It seemed to me that the SelectMany could be used to this end, but I am not getting what I expected.

How should the function above be modified?

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you explain properly means is there any error you are getting? what is sample input and expected output?

Comment: There is an error in your original LINQ around `.Count`.

Comment: @HiteshThakor no error... except those that I get inside the IDE. I'm mainly struggling with how to write a query that select all the Module out of Modules which, apart from other things, have at least one Point with the same Location and an empty Connection field.

Comment: @NetMage which error?

Comment: You have 6 open parentheses and 7 close parentheses in your original LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what the `SimilarPoint(t.Type, x)` does here. 

May be you should try something like this and find out if it works for you -

```
var resultSet = Modules.Where(m => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(m.Type) && m.ID.Equals("A"))
                .Select(n => 
                    new Module {
                        Type=n.Type,
                        ID=n.ID,
                        Points= n.Points.Where(p => String.IsNullOrEmpty(p.Connection) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(p.Location)).ToList()
                    })
                .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You said all the returned modules have the same `Location`, but that doesn't explain how you select which `Location` so I arbitrarily picked the first matching module's location:

```
var miQuery1 = Modules.Where(m => m.Type != null
                             && m.ID == "A"
                             && m.Points.Where(t => t.Connection == ""
                                && SimilarPoint(t.Type, x).ToList()).Count() > 0)
                        .Where(m => m.Points.All(p => p.Connection == ""));
var miQuery2 = miQuery1.Where(m => m.Location == miQuery1.First().Location);
List<Module> miList = miQuery2.ToList();
```

Comment: `.Where(m => m.Points.All(p => p.Connection == ""));` is a not correct... not all points need to have an empty connection

Comment: But your original question states:  **shall all have points with Connection equal to ""**

Comment: Poor wording on my part. The idea here is that the returned modules shall  have at least one point with the same Location value and "empty" Connection...

Comment: same Location value of what?